# What is the difference between a partition and a subinterval?

Tags: calculus, integration, terminology, definition

For example the norm of a partition is the widest subinterval

Comment: A partition of an interval can give you several subintervals.

Comment: If $[a, b] $ is a closed interval then a partition $P$ of $[a, b] $ is a finite set of points from that interval including both the end points $a, b$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stackexchange! I've shortened your title to make it more on point and added the terminology and definition tags.

Comment: I also suggest that you [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3983221/edit) your question to explain the context a little better.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a formal definition of [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_an_interval) of intervals:

> In mathematics, a partition of an interval $[a, b]$ on the real line is a finite sequence $x_0, x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ of real numbers such that
> $$
> a = x_0 < x_1 < x_2 < ... < x_n = b.
> $$

Such partition gives you $n$ "subintervals" of $[a,b]$,
$$
[x_{k-1},x_{k}],\quad k=1,\cdots,n\tag{1}
$$

The **norm** (or mesh) of the partition
$$
x_0 < x_1 < x_2 < ... < x_n
$$
is the length of the longest of the subintervals in (1):
$$
\max\{|x_i − x_{i−1}| : i = 1, ... , n \}.
$$

---

To see a simple example for the interval $[0,10]$,
take the partition:
$$
0<1<6<8.5<10
$$
This partition gives you four subintervels:
$$
[0,1],\quad [1,6],\quad [6,8.5],\quad [8.5,10]
$$
and the norm of this partition is $5$.

Answer (score 4):

A partition of an interval is a division of the interval into subintervals; the subintervals are the ‘pieces’ of the partition, so to speak, the subintervals of which the partition is composed.

The norm of a partition is **not** the sidest subinterval of the partition: it is the **width** of the widest subinterval. Consider, for instance, the partition of $[0,1]$ into subintervals $\left[0,\frac13\right],\left[\frac13,\frac12\right]$, and $\left[\frac12,1\right]$. The partition is this collection of subintervals. The lengths of the subintervals are $\frac13,\frac16$, and $\frac12$, so the norm of the partition is $\frac12$; it is **not* the interval $\left[\frac12,1\right]$.

Comment: I thought the norm of the partition P is the length of the widest subinterval? I am also a little confused where 1/6 came from. Sorry if this is a stupid q.

Comment: @fintechgenie: Yes, that is what I said: It the length (or width, if you prefer — same thing) of the widest subinterval. $\frac16=\frac12-\frac13$, the width of the middle interval.

Comment: Oh my bad sir thank you so much for the explanation!!! appreciate it!!

Comment: @fintechgenie: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 0):

A partition of a set $S$ is a collection of subsets $S_i\subset S$ such that the union $\bigcup S_i=S,$ and each distinct $S_i$ have empty intersection. In the case of $S=[a,b]\subset \Bbb R^1$, this gives you non-overlapping subintervals of $[a,b]$ which together forms the entirety of $[a,b]$.